# first-child not selecting expected elements

Tags: jquery

I'm in a situation in which I need to use .wrap and :first-child.

This is what I am doing:

```
<script>$("a").wrap("<div class='category-wrapper'></div>");</script>
<script>$("div.category-wrapper:first-child").addClass("first");</script>
```

This should render a div.category-wrapper outside a link and then add a "first" class to every first div.category-wrapper.

The output is:

```
<div class="category-wrapper"><a href="#">Test</a></div>
```

Which is good! However, I am not able to get the "first-child" to work (it doesn't adds the "first" class). If I use it somewhere else it works so I am sure it's something related to the dynamic rendering of the previous element.

Sample output would be:

```
<div class="category-wrapper"><a href="#">Test #1</a></div>
<div class="category-wrapper"><a href="#">Test #2</a></div>
<div class="category-wrapper"><a href="#">Test #3</a></div>
<div class="category-wrapper"><a href="#">Test #4</a></div>
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="category-wrapper first"><a href="#">Test #1</a></div>
<div class="category-wrapper"><a href="#">Test #2</a></div>
<div class="category-wrapper"><a href="#">Test #3</a></div>
<div class="category-wrapper"><a href="#">Test #4</a></div>
```

However, I am not able to make it work.

Comment: Show us some HTML. `:first-child` will have trouble if this is a text with links scattered all over it.

Comment: The "first-child" thing is only going to work when those `<div>` elements are actually the first child of their parent container.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with the sample output and the desired output.

Comment: Well @Johann what *else* is in the page around those `<div>` blocks you add?  In other words, what comes right before the very first `<div>` you add?

Comment: Your code is fine. I get your desired output. http://jsfiddle.net/8CBfv/

Comment: @patrick see what happens if you put something random like a `<span>` before the first `<a>` in your test

Comment: @Pointy - Certainly structural changes affect selectors.

Comment: Right - the point is that the question doesn't show the most important thing, which is what surrounded the `<a>` tags *before* they were wrapped.  If the first `<div>` produced by the wrap comes *after* anything else that was already there, then it will not be the "first child".

Comment: Pointy, I got what you were saying based on @KatieK answer. It changes the whole thing if there are elements surrounding the element or not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Patrick, thanks for the sample code. Indeed it worked, the thing is that I had surrounding code all over (I just wanted to post the "relevant code") but in this case as @Pointy was asking, it was important to know since it changes the whole picture of the question.

Comment: @Johann - It's good that you narrow things down. Helps in reading code. A little broader perspective can be important though too (as you can see). :o)

Comment: @Pointy - Certainly. I was merely demonstrating that given the HTML provided, the jQuery code was behaving as expected. That is why I posted it as a *comment* instead of an answer, as it would not resolve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first-child depends on the context of the element you're trying to select: ["Description: Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent."](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/).

Check this out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>First Child Exp</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.first { background-color: red; }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>First Child Exp</h1>

<div>
<div class="category-wrapper"><a href="#">Test</a></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("div.category-wrapper:first-child").addClass("first");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you delete the div with no class, then div class="category-wrapper" will be the second child of it's parent, since the h1 will be the first child of body.  If you then delete the h1, div class="category-wrapper" will again be the first child of body.

So, a parent element must surround all of the div class="category-wrapper" elements.

Comment: Awesome @KatieK . I was struggling with this but this is the best example and explanation for sure! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried $("div.category-wrapper a:first-child") ?

Comment: He wants the class to be added to the `<div>`, not the `<a>`.

Comment: I've edited the question so you can check the desired output.

Comment: I have just tried your code and it works fine I have uploaded an example at www.nicklansdell.com/stack/ look at it with firebug

Comment: Thanks a lot for your sample code. However, I didn't took in considerating there were surrounding elements that were affecting this. Your code helped me anyways as a sample to organize mine since I was loading several scripts at the same time instead of just one with all the code in it!

Answer (score 2):

If you have something like this:

```
<div>
  Hello there
  <span>Somethiing something</span>
  <a href='somewhere'>wrap me</a>
```

Then when that `<a>` tag is wrapped you'll have this:

```
<div>
  Hello there
  <span>Somethiing something</span>
  <div class='category-wrapper'><a href='somewhere'>wrap me</a></div>
```

That added `<div>` is **not** the first child of the containing `<div>`.

It might work for you to use ":first" instead of ":first-child". Those two are of course not always interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code @Pointy. This works to understand the "big picture" of this issue!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("a").wrap("<div class='category-wrapper'></div>");
$("div.category-wrapper:first").children().addClass('first');
```